# Object reference not set to an instance of an object.#HttpContext

Tags: nullreferenceexception, object-reference

hi i'm trying to get the current context with httpContext, but i get a System.NullReferenceException exception, don't know why cos every thing seem clear on the code
here is my property:

```
private static string ShoppingCartId
{
    get
    {
        //on obtient le HttpContext actuel
        HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
        //on essaie d'extraire l'id stockés dans le cookie de l'utilisateur actuel

        string cartId = context.Request.Cookies["LUP_CartID"].Value;

        //si l'id du Cart n'est pas dans le cookie
        {
            //on vérifie si l'id du cart existe en tant que cookie
            if (context.Request.Cookies["LUP_CartID"] != null)
            {
                //on retourne l'id
                return cartId;
            }
```

the Exception comes from this line : "string cartId = context.Request.Cookies["LUP_CartID"].Value;"

Answer (score 0):

the cookie LUP_CartID doens't exist. context.Request.Cookies["LUP_CartID"] is returning null, when you call context.Request.Cookies["LUP_CartID"].Value you're trhying to ivnvoke null.Value . Check if context.Request.Cookies["LUP_CartID"] is not null.

Comment: yes, that's what i'm doing at this line:                              if (context.Request.Cookies["LUP_CartID"] != null)
            {
                //on retourne l'id
                return cartId;
            }

Comment: @djasy3 you nedd to check before accessing it, first you're trying to access it and then you checking it's value.